# sudo apt-get update error

Tags: apt

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Bad header line [IP: 216.58.197.46 80]"

W: Failed to fetch "http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 216.58.197.46 80]"

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

how to correct this errors

Comment: `http//dl.google.com`?! That's not a valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your files to point to `http://` instead of `http//`.

First, run the following command to fix your `sources.list`:

```
sudo sed -i 's|http/|http:/|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, run the following command to fix your google-chrome.list:

```
sudo sed -i s|http/|http:/|g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Finally, run the following command to update `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I'd bet that OP removed the colons because they don't know how to use code formatting, and as a new user, they can't post more than two links. And that this isn't the solution.

Comment: @muru I believe you are correct. I don't see why there is also a 404 on 
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages so I'll leave the answer up just in case. In the mean time, I've voted it as a duplicate.

Comment: considering the other error (bad header), a captive portal intercepting HTTP requests?